# Install Debian Backports kernel automatically

Tags: debian, apt, debian-wheezy, package-management, pinning

I've got the following pinnings set:

```
Package: linux-image-amd64
Pin: release a=wheezy-backports
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=wheezy-backports
Pin-Priority: 499
```

I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 but it is not going to   be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The policies seem to be correct:

```
$ apt-cache policy linux-image-amd64
linux-image-amd64:
  Installed: 3.2+46
  Candidate: 3.16+63~bpo70+1
  Package pin: 3.16+63~bpo70+1
  Version table:
     3.16+63~bpo70+1 1001
        499 http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.2+46 1001
        500 http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt-cache policy linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.16.7-ckt4-3~bpo70+1
  Version table:
     3.16.7-ckt4-3~bpo70+1 0
        499 http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages
```

So I don't get the error. What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to use puppet to upgrade all Wheezy machines to the backports kernel (a reboot streak is planned), which is why I want to solve it correctly. I could manually login to all servers to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -t wheezy-backports linux-image-amd64
```

Which works, but is not as convenient.

UPDATE

As requested:

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d$ cat linux-image 
Package: linux-image-*
Pin: release a=wheezy-backports
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=wheezy-backports
Pin-Priority: 499

/etc/apt/preferences.d$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://debian.kumina.nl wheezy-kumina Release.gpg
.
.
.
Reading package lists... Done
/etc/apt/preferences.d$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
/etc/apt/preferences.d$ aptitude why-not linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Unable to find a reason to remove linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check what that package depends on and what those dependencies need as well.
For example I see this for my machine:

```
#apt-cache  show linux-image-amd64
Package: linux-image-amd64
<snip>
Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

and

```
# apt-cache  show linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
Package: linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
<snip>
Depends: kmod | module-init-tools, linux-base (>= 3~), debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, initramfs-tools (>= 0.110~) | linux-initramfs-tool
Pre-Depends: debconf | debconf-2.0
```

Check if dependencies are taken from backports as well.

Comment: That's already explained in my question...

Comment: I don't see anything about pinning dependencies version in your question. you need to configure higher priority for packages needed for linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64. check this out: ```Depends: kmod | module-init-tools, linux-base (>= 3~), debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, initramfs-tools (>= 0.110~) | dracut (>= 0.40+1-1~) | linux-initramfs-tool```. If you using `dracut` for example, Wheezy has version `020-2 0`, while backports have `040+1-1 0`. In thiks case you need to increase priority of Dracut package to be taken from backports as well.

Comment: Wouldn't those be pulled in as well when I install it via 'apt-get -t wheezy-backports install linux-image-amd64'?

Comment: It will, if you enforce it with `-t wheezy-backports`. But this enforcement will also install all newer versions for not installed dependencies from backports as well, regardless of fact if stable versions are enough or not. If you need to install only limited and controlled number of packages from backports, you need to track the dependencies and manually pin them. If you don't care about that, sure go ahead and do full `-t *backports`.

Comment: Ah got it, you're right. I needed to fetch initramfs-tools from backports as well and then it can be done automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> sudo apt-get install -t wheezy-backports linux-image-amd64

it is not convenient I know .. but it is the right way to do things without having troubles in future (IMHO of course)

Comment: What troubles in the future would you expect with this?

Comment: - if debian has engineered its system to work one way I "suppose" they have their good reason ;) (see [backports Instructions](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/))
- pinning the entire source you give a higher priority to a wide number of packages being recompiled from testing and unstable and not tested as the stable couterparts
- the philosophy using `-t` is to let the package to install its dependencies .. "do strictly what you need" .. 
- its a while list approach: do what you are aware to do, when you need

Comment: This doesn't have enough upvotes

Answer (score 1):

Change the top line in your preferences to

```
Package: linux-image-*
```

Run

```
apt-get update
```

Try to install again.  If you still get the error, check

```
aptitude why-not linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Added the command output to my question.

Comment: OK, thanks for trying.  I'd be inclined to use the `aptitude` resolver interactively to identify the problem.  Maybe `linux-*` to include other dependencies?  Is it feasible to add `APT::Default-Release "wheezy-backports";` to the configuration temporarily?

Comment: We actually remove aptitude from all our servers, I had to install it to do the test. So that won't be feasible. Adding the config option temporarily is not feasible and, honestly, not really a nice solution :) I'm pretty sure this should be doable with apt-get without any hacks, just can't figure out how!